# Is there a way to optimize the code and improve to K number of sum terms instead of 4?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
  int N = 133;
  int a, b, c, d;
  int flag = 0;
    for ( int j = 1; j < (N/2); j++)
    {
     a = j;
      for ( int k = 1; k < (N/2); k++)
      {
      b = k;
        for ( int l = 1; l < (N/2); l++)
      {
        c = l;
        for ( int m = 1; m < (N/2); m++)
        {
        d = m;       
        if ( a+b+c+d == N && (a != 0 && b!= 0 && c != 0 && d!= 0))
        {
                printf("\n %d + %d + %d + %d = %d" , a, b, c, d, N);
                flag = 1;
                break;
        }
        }
        if(flag)
          break;
      }   
        if(flag)
          break;
      }   
        if(flag)
          break;
    }
return 0;
}
```

The code currently outputs

```
1 + 2 + 65 + 65 = 133
```

As you can see, I am getting the sum using 4 numbers to form N (133) in this case. Is there a way to improve the code to 'k' numbers without using nested 'k' for loops?

```
Desired Output: ( a + b + c + d + e + f + ...... + k = N )
```

say for a given value of N represented using sum of k terms, where k is an input parameter.

Notes:

- None of the 'k' terms is zero.
- Original question had loops starting from 0; updated to start from 1.
- Specific Requirement, I want the terms (a to k) to have the lowest possible standard deviation among all the sums. So breaking out at the first sum is not ideal for that scenario, but this is the baseline code I have reached. Once I figure out reducing number of loops, I know how to modify for lowest S.D.
- Also pretty obvious but k < N in all cases.

Comment: I've limited the inner loops to run till N/2 , just for simplicity.

Comment: You must learn about the recursion - when a function calls itself.

Comment: Not what you're asking, but an optimization that *jumps right into your face* would be to start all the loops at `1`. You don't care for results with a `0` summand anyways!

Comment: For the question: specify your exact requirements. A *trivial* solution for any `N > k` would be `(k-1)* 1 + (N-k+1)` (example: `N=65, k=5`, solution `1+1+1+1+61`) -- probably not what you're after.

Comment: Any reason for the downvotes I'm seeing, Let me know so that I can improve the question or the way of questioning.

Comment: Don't know about the DVs, but please don't edit the code in your question in response to suggestions from the comments or answers. This makes your question a moving target. This will make it difficult for future readers to make sense of comments and answers when they don't match your question anymore.

Comment: @deathbycode As pointed out above, the problem (as stated by you) has a trivial solution that can be found in no time at all without the use of loops or recursion.

Comment: @IvanKuckir-- I am not convinced that recursion is the path to optimization here....

Comment: Thanks @DavidBowling , will keep that in mind.

Comment: @squeamish ossifrage Do you refer to the solution from Felix ? If so, I have updated the question for specific requirements which is beyond the trivial solution I believe. Thanks.

Comment: Isn't the minimum standard deviation going to be when the terms are such that they are all `N/k` or `(N/k)+1` so that when they're added up, they equal `N`?  So you really don't need to do all the looping.  (You'll need `N%k` terms with value `(N/k)+1` and the remainder with the value `N/k`, won't you?  At least for `k > 2`; there are some definitional issues if N is odd and `k == 2`.)  Of course, a non-iterative solution deprives you of the opportunity to learn about recursion, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Much simpler code that does the same thing as yours:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
  int N = 133;
  for ( int j = 1; j < (N/2); j++)
    for ( int k = 1; k < (N/2); k++)
      for ( int l = 1; l < (N/2); l++)
        for ( int m = 1; m < (N/2); m++)
          if ( j+k+l+m == N) {
            printf("\n %d + %d + %d + %d = %d" , j, k, l , m, N);
            return 0;
          }
}
```

And to your problem, which is a bit vague, but seems to be finding k numbers a_1, a_2 ... a_k such that 1 < a_n < N/2 for all n and a_1+a_2+...+a_k=N. Here is very simple code to do that, using your algorithm but extended for arbitrary k:

```
#define N 133
#define k 8

int main()
{
  int arr[k];
  for(int i=0; i<k; i++)
    arr[i]=1;
  for(int i=0,c=k; c<N; c++) {
    arr[i]++;
    if(arr[i]>=N/2) {
      c--;
      i++;
    }
  }
  for(int i=0; i<k-2; i++)
    printf("%d + ", arr[i]);
  printf("%d = %d\n", arr[k-1], N);
}
```

It has no error checking. The problem is not solvable for k=1 and k>N. And because integer division is rounded down, it is not solvable for k=2 if N is odd.

But here is some MUCH more efficient code. The problem is very simple, so it's not about finding the numbers a_1, a_2, a_3 ... a_k. It's really only about finding a_1 and a_2. The rest are one.

```
#define N 19
#define k 5

int main()
{
  for(int i=0; i<k-2; i++)
    printf("1 + ");

  int c=N/2-(k-2);
  if (c<1)
    c=1;
  printf("%d + ", c);
  printf("%d = %d\n", N-(k-2)-c, N);
}
```

Again, no error check is made.

Comment: Hmmm. The lack of braces here seems to make the scopes of the variables `j,...,m` less than obvious.

Comment: @DavidBowling Some prefer braces even for one statement. I don't.

Comment: Thanks, this is really helpful. :)

Comment: Yes, I am aware of that convention. I don't prefer it for various reasons, but fine with me if others use it. I was pointing out that you have several loop-scoped variables here, and it is not as clear where their scopes end without the braces. Especially for learners.

Comment: @DavidBowling As long as you have proper indentation I don't see the problem. Works fine in Python. :)